# Squid is giving me 403 from time to time

Tags: squid

I have a squid server that is used by a lots of collage.

This is the squid config:

```
dns_v4_first on

# ACL Squid
external_acl_type is_user ipv4 ttl=600 negative_ttl=10 children-max=2000 %SRC /opt/acl_squid.py

# ACL PROXY Access
acl is_real_user external is_user

#acl SSL method CONNECT
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
#acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
#acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
#acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
#acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
#acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
#acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
#acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl SSL method CONNECT
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6 # Enable IPv6

http_access deny !Safe_ports

# ACL Allow Host/Domain
http_access allow is_real_user
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

# Enable IPv6
#tcp_outgoing_address ipv6_address to_ipv6
# Port
http_port 0.0.0.0:3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid


refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

# Chache Off
cache deny all

# Performance tuning
maximum_object_size 1 MB
maximum_object_size_in_memory 128 KB
cache_mem 64 MB
quick_abort_min 1024 KB
quick_abort_max 2048 KB
quick_abort_pct 90
pipeline_prefetch on
shutdown_lifetime 1 second

# Log
access_log syslog:local3.info squid
```

The external ACL is just checking the request IP to be sure that has access to that proxy (its checking via API to a DB to see if the IP exists there).

The issue is that from time to time (not only me, lots of collage) I'm receiving 403 (access denied) for no reason.

Could you please let me know what exactly I can do in order to have access all the time with no interruption?

What I do when I'm receiving 403 is to restart the squid server and the everything is back to normal.

Regards,
Ciprian

Comment: What do the logs show for the 403's? `/var/log/squid/access.log` Also which version of squid is this?

Comment: the version is 3.5.12 and the log shows something like: 19:55:13 us1-yn (squid-1): 1498679713.675     IP TCP_DENIED/403 4034 CONNECT DOMAIN - HIER_NONE/- text/html

Comment: Did you find a way to fix it?